# Are there any good examples on how to use Haskell monad functions?

Tags: haskell, monads

Haskell monad functions are not easy to understand, where can I find usage examples?

Comment: here is an implementation:

Answer (score 3):

You mean the functions with names like `fooM` and `fooM_`? You can understand them better possibly by reading their source code, or when you write a `do`-expression, you could think if that can be expressed with a relevant `fooM`-function.

You could also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412929/creative-uses-of-monads#412992).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a case study called ["Anatomy of a New Monad"](http://paulspontifications.blogspot.com/2007/08/anatomy-of-new-monad.html).  Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

The answer I was looking for is:
[A tour of the Haskell monad functions][1]

But I'm still looking for something similar for the non standard monads.

[1]: http://members.chello.nl/hjgtuyl/tourdemonad.html A tour of the Haskell monad functions

Answer (score 2):

The new O'Reilly book *Real World Haskell* has some good chapters on monads, which include the kind of <strike>wacky ad hoc user-defined</strike> abstract monad function stuff you seem to be looking for.

Comment: You can find that book here: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/
(Saving you a trip to Google :-)